# strcpy : how can i not copy \n

Tags: c, strcpy

```
struct configurations *read_file(char * file_name)
{ 
    FILE *f = fopen(file_name ,"r");
    if(!f)
    {
        printf("**********Unable to open config.txt*********");
        return NULL;
    }

    int i, prev, count;
    char *line = NULL, buff[480] = {'\0'};
    size_t len;

    struct configurations *config = (struct configurations *) malloc(sizeof(struct configurations));

    while (getline(&line,&len,f) != -1)
    {
        if(!strncmp("SERVERPORT = ",line,strlen("SERVERPORT = "))){
            config->server_Port = atoi(strstr(line, " = ")+3);
        }
        else if(!strncmp("SCHEDULING = ",line,strlen("SCHEDULING = "))){
            strcpy(config->sched,strstr(line, " = ") + 3);


        }
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: This function can't skip `\n` character as I know. Just make it in loop. Although, maybe I didn't get your question,

Comment: You could use `fgets` which reads until the newline (then copy len-1 bytes from it to skip the newline). Or just use `fscanf("%s\n")`

Comment: @jefferson the strings shown contains spaces so that `fscanf` won't work as written.

Comment: Oh, I understood) Then solution above will work, although it has low speed. But you need to sure that file uses `\n` line ending. It can use `\r` or `\r\n`.

Comment: You don't explain your code, this code doesn't compile. You need to learn how to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here you just post all your code and say do it for me. Please upgrade your question because I see no reason to help you here.

Comment: @Шах Are you sure that just \r is valid for a new line ? Never saw that.

Comment: It has. And no it isn't a `new line` it returns a carriet (I don't know how to write, sorry).

Comment: i resolved it , i made a strcpy (aux1,aux2,len(aux2)-1)

Answer (score 1):

- By subctracting `1` from the length.

There are multiple simple and obvious improvements to your code

1. You should always check the return value before using from `strstr()`.
2. `strlen("SERVERPORT = ")` is a very ugly way of writing 12, inefficient too.
3. You should use a little bit more white spaces to make the code readable.
4. Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` it only makes it more difficult to read and might hide a bug if you forget to include *stdlib.h*.
5. ALWAYS check if `malloc()` returned `NULL` before dereferencing the pointer.
6. Split every line at `=`, remove all surrounding white spaces from the 2 resulting values and then check which variable it is and assign the corresponding value.

   As it is your code will fail if `SERVERPORT=1234` for example, and even if it's ugly and spaces around the `=` operator are better, both should be valid unless of course you explicitly want the spaces.

   Also by removing surrounding white spaces you ensure that any  `'\n'` that was read by `getline()` will be removed from the value.

This is a quick API a wrote just now to show you how I would do it, of course every one has their own taste and ways to do things, but I hope it helps figuring out your mistakes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct KeyValue {
    char *key;
    char *value;
};

struct KeyFile {
    size_t size;
    struct KeyValue *entries;
    size_t count;
};

static struct KeyFile *
keyfile_new(void)
{
    struct KeyFile *kf;

    kf = malloc(sizeof(*kf));
    if (kf == NULL)
        return NULL;
    kf->entries = malloc(10 * sizeof(*kf->entries));
    if (kf->entries == NULL) {
        kf->size = 0;
    } else {
        kf->size = 10;
    }
    kf->count = 0;
    return kf;
}

static int
keyfile_add_value(struct KeyFile *kf, const char *const key, const char *const value)
{
    struct KeyValue *entry;
    if (kf->count + 1 >= kf->size) {
        void *pointer;
        pointer = realloc(kf->entries, (kf->size + 10) * sizeof(*kf->entries));
        if (pointer == NULL)
            return -1;
        kf->entries = pointer;
        kf->size += 10;
    }
    entry = &kf->entries[kf->count++];

    entry->key = strdup(key);
    entry->value = strdup(value);

    return 0;
}

static void
keyfile_free(struct KeyFile *kf) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < kf->count ; ++i) {
        struct KeyValue *entry;

        entry = &kf->entries[i];

        free(entry->key);
        free(entry->value);
    }
    free(kf->entries);
    free(kf);
}

static struct KeyFile *
keyfile_read(const char *const path)
{
    FILE *file;
    struct KeyFile *kf;
    size_t length;
    char *line;

    line = NULL;
    length = 0;
    file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;
    kf = keyfile_new();
    if (kf == NULL)
        return NULL;
    while (getline(&line, &length, file) > 0) {
        char *op;
        char *key;
        char *value;
        op = strchr(line, '=');
        if (op == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malformed line!\n");
        } else {
            *op = '\0';
            key = line;
            while (isspace((unsigned char) *key) != 0)
                ++key;
            value = op + 1;

            op -= 1;
            while (isspace((unsigned char) *op) != 0)
                *(op--) = '\0';
            while (isspace((unsigned char) *value) != 0)
                value += 1;
            op = value + strlen(value) - 1;
            while (isspace((unsigned char) *op) != 0)
                *(op--) = '\0';
            if (keyfile_add_value(kf, key, value) != 0)
                goto error;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    free(line);

    return kf;
error:
    keyfile_free(kf);

    fclose(file);
    free(line);    

    return NULL;
}

static void
keyfile_display(const struct KeyFile *const kf)
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < kf->count ; ++i) {
        const struct KeyValue *entry;

        entry = &kf->entries[i];
        fprintf(stdout, "/%s/ => /%s/\n", entry->key, entry->value);
    }
}
```

You could improve this to add lookup functions, to find specific values in the settings file. And you can make it a standalone library to use it in many projects too.